# What gets called when you initialize a class without a constructor?

Tags: java, class, constructor, initializing

So when a class has a private constructor you can't initialize it, but when it doesn't have a constructor you can. So what is called when you initialize a class without a constructor?

As example, what is called here (new b())??

```
public class a {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        b classB = new b();
    }
}

public class b {
    public void aMethod() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "class without a constructor" in Java - if there's no *explicit* constructor in the source code the compiler automatically adds a default one to the class file:

```
public ClassName() {
  super();
}
```

This in turn can fail to compile if the superclass doesn't have a public or protected no-argument constructor itself.

Answer (score 2):

It's called the default constructor. It's automatically added when a class doesn't *explicitly* define any constructors.

[Formal specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.8.9):

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default
>   constructor that takes no parameters is automatically provided:
>   If the class being declared is the primordial class Object, then the default
>   constructor has an empty body.
>  
>   Otherwise, the default constructor takes no parameters and simply invokes the
>   superclass constructor with no arguments.

Answer (score 2):

the default no argument constructor is invoked - see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) for more information

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, use `javap`.

`Empty.java`:

```
public class Empty {
    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

Then:

```
javac Empty.java
javap -v Empty.class
```

Output excerpt:

```
public Empty();
  descriptor: ()V
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC
  Code:
    stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
```

Ha! A constructor got generated. If we try the same for:

```
public class Empty {
    public Empty() {}
    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

we see exactly the same bytecode.

I have asked if this is a Java-only restriction or if it is also present on the bytecode-level at: [Is it valid to have a JVM bytecode class without any constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478139/is-it-valid-to-have-a-jvm-bytecode-class-without-any-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

There is an invisible default constructor that looks something like this:

```
public B() {
   super();
}
```

When you call `new B()`, this implicit constructor gets called.

One note, in Java we use the convention that class names begin with an uppercase alphabetic character. So I have changed that for you.